# How to change simulator device in xcode 11.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11.4

xcode 11.4 has removed the standard "hardware" and device options from Simulator. How to open an existing device or create a new device?

Here is the new simulator menu:

[image]

---

In xcode 11.4, Windows > Devices and Simulators, there is no option to launch a simulator.

[image]

Comment: Are you running your app from Xcode? If so, just select the device for the Active Scheme (top-left): https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMhYk.png ... if not, then search for `launch ios simulator from command line`

Comment: Oh... do you not have this option? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUMwY.png

Comment: @DonMag Found the option, thanks. My bad I couldn't find it earlier.

Comment: Added as an answer, for the benefit of anyone else coming across this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running your app from Xcode, just select the device for the Active Scheme (top-left):

[image]

If not, then search for `launch ios simulator from command line`

Or, find this option:

[image]